# CakePHP 3 Get Current Host in View

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am attempting to build the full URI for images in my view, however, I am unsuccessful at this time because I am unsure of how to get the current host inside a view template...

How do I get the host/domain of the current url inside of a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->request->host()` will give you the current host, but you shouldn't need that. The [HTML helper's `image` function](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images) can accept a `fullBase` option which will cause it to generate full URLs.